# If $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible over $F$, and let $E$ the splitting of $f(x)$.

Tags: galois-theory

Then, supposing that $[E:F] = p^k$, for $p$ prime. Then $f$ is solvable by radicals.

I can't think in a tower of roots to solve the problem. Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ is a $p$-group, and any $p$-group is solvable.

The latter assertion is easy to proof: A $p$-group $G$ has non-trivial center. $Z(G)$ is abelian, hence solvable. $G/Z(G)$ is solvable by induction, so we get the result.